# Directives are not updated when ng-repeat changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a directive that is repeated using `ng-repeat`. Consider this code:

```
<my-drctv todos="todos" ng-repeat="todos in todoGroups track by todos[0].id"></my-drctv>
```

`todoGroups` is a two dimensional array, that contains grouped todos.

This is my directive:

```
angular.module('myModule').directive('myDrctv', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      todos: "="
    },
    replace: true,
    templateUrl: '<div>{{firstTodo.description}}</div>',
    link: function link(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
      console.log("myDrctv: link fn");
      scope.firstTodo = scope.todos[0];
    }
  };
});
```

This lists my todos (the template is simplified) and works so far.

**Now the problem**: When `todoGroups` is re-fetched from my server and set to a new value with `$scope.todoGroups = myService.fetch()` inside my controller, my directives aren't updated, because the link function of my directive isn't called a second time.

> - It seems that this problem occurs only, when the length of the list returned by the server is the same as before and only the "content" of my todos are changed (but I'm not sure)
> - Does angular re-use my directives for performance reasons? I always thought, it would destroy every element inside `ng-repeat` and insert new elements (in my case a directive)
> - How can I trigger a second call to my `link` function of my directive?

Comment: just a thought if you getting your values with $http check if your cache is false i had a similar problem

Comment: I checked it and there are new todos from the server. I can access them in my controller, only the directive isnt updated

Comment: ok apparantly you have to add $watch because the  link function runs only once.if you need example just say it.

Comment: If you get new array from server - all your objects change, so ng-repeat will update correctly. So your statement is wrong.

If, however you will use 'track by $index' expression, then elements will be reused and view will not be updated. You need watch in this case.

http://plnkr.co/edit/CRNM4oV9cbU9TCYefxVp?p=preview

Comment: @PetrAveryanov Thanks for your comment! I had indeed a `track by` statement in my `ng-repeat` (but forgot to include it in my question, udpated). The solution was to add a unique `trackBy` field, that depends on the state of the todo. If you add your comment as an answer, I'll be happy to accept it.

Comment: change your track by sentence to `track by todos[$index].id`

Comment: Why not just `track by id`?

Comment: I can't use `track by todos[$index].id` or `track by id` because maybe only the content of the todo has changed, then `ng-repeat` would not update correctly, as @PetrAveryanov pointed out.